# Python multiprocessing process vs. standalone Python VM

Tags: python, multiprocessing, virtual-machine

Aside from the ease of use of the `multiprocessing` module when it comes to hooking up processes with communication resources, are there any other differences between spawning multiple processes using `multiprocessing` compared to using `subprocess` to launch separate Python VMs ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On Posix platforms, `multiprocessing` primitives essentially wrap an `os.fork()`. What this means is that at point you spawn a process in multiprocessing, the code already imported/initialized remains so in the child process.

This can be a boon if you have a lot of things to initialize and then each subprocess essentially performs operations on (copies of) those initialized objects, but not all that helpful if the thing you run in the subprocess is completely unrelated.

There are also implications for resources such as file-handles, sockets, etc with `multiprocessing` on a unix-like platform.

Meanwhile, when using `subprocess`, you are creating an entirely new program/interpreter each time you `Popen` a new process. This means there can be less shared memory between them, but it also means you can Popen into a completely separate program, or a new entry-point into the same program.

On Windows, the differences are less between `multiprocessing` and `subprocess`, because windows does not provide `fork()`.

Comment: Microsoft does provide `fork()` in high-end versions of Windows. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5372260/95735) for details.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost But I do not believe "multiprocessing" on windows takes advantage of this.

Comment: You could choose to use spawn system call on *nix systems as of Python 3.4+

Answer (score 5):

If you ignore any communication issues (i.e., if the separate Python VMs do not communicate among themselves, or communicate only through other mechanisms that are explicitly established), there are no other substantial differences.  (I believe `multiprocessing`, under certain conditions -- Unix-like platforms, in particular -- can use the more efficient `fork` rather than the fork-exec pair always implied by `multiprocessing` -- but that's not "substantial" when just a few processes are involved [[IOW, the performance difference on startup will not be material to the performance of the whole system]]).