# Substitute for forking in windows

Tags: c++, winapi, gcc, winsock, fork

I've been following [Beej Networking guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/clientserver.html) and in the server section there is portion of code where it has called a function fork().

```
if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
            close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
            if (send(new_fd, "Hello, world!", 13, 0) == -1)
                perror("send");
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
```

I'm on a windows machine and cant get that part working. What can I do to solve this?.
My code is as follows.

```
/* Server */
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>


using namespace std;

const int winsockVersion = 2;
#define BACKLOG 10
#define PORT "3000"


int main(void){

    WSADATA wsadata;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(winsockVersion,0),&wsadata) == 0){
        cout<<"-WSAStartup initialized..." << endl;

        int status;
        int sockfd, new_fd;
        const char yes = '1';
        struct addrinfo hints, *res,*loop_find;
        struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
        socklen_t addr_size;



        memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

        if ( (status = getaddrinfo(NULL,PORT,&hints,&res)) == 0 ){
            cout<<"-Call to get addrinfo successful!." << endl;
        }

        for (loop_find = res; loop_find!=NULL; loop_find = loop_find->ai_next){
            if ( (sockfd = socket(loop_find->ai_family,loop_find->ai_socktype,loop_find->ai_protocol) ) == -1 ){
                cout<<"-Could not create socket." << endl;
                continue;
            }else{
                cout<<"-Socket Created." << endl;
            }

            //clearing in use ports.
            if (setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&yes,sizeof(int)) == -1) {
                cout<<"-Couldnt clear blocked port." << endl;
                perror("setsockopt");
                exit(1);
            }

            if( bind(sockfd,loop_find->ai_addr,loop_find->ai_addrlen) == -1 ){
                closesocket(sockfd);
                perror("server: bind");
                continue;
            }

            break;
        }

        if (listen(sockfd,BACKLOG) != -1){
            cout<<"-Listening for incoming connections.";
        }

        //accept loop.
        while(true){

            socklen_t addr_size = sizeof their_addr;
            new_fd = accept(sockfd,(sockaddr*)&their_addr,&addr_size);

            if ( new_fd == -1 ){
                perror("accept");
                continue;
            }

            struct sockaddr new_addr;
            int len = sizeof new_addr;
            getpeername(new_fd,&new_addr,&len);
            cout<<"-Connected to " << new_addr.sa_data << endl;

            if(!fork()){ //this is a child process
                closesocket(sockfd);
                if (send(new_fd,"hello world!!",13,0) == -1){
                    perror("send");
                    closesocket(new_fd);
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            closesocket(new_fd);

        }
    }


    //clear stuff
    if( WSACleanup() != 0){
        cout<<"-WSACleanup unsuccessful" << endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"-WSACleanup successful" << endl;
    }


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: When you code for Windows, you usually use another kind of thinking. I think you are better off looking at Winsock tutorials instead of this guide you are using.

Comment: Related questions: [What is the closest thing windows has to fork()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985281/), [CreateThread vs fork()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619019/), [fork/chroot equivalent for Windows server application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686578/), [Where does Microsoft Windows 7 POSIX implementation currently stands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746043/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

fork() obviously doesn't exist on Windows. Instead you'll need to [create a new thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453(VS.85).aspx), or a [whole new process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: But in reality you simply don't design network servers like that on Windows.

Comment: fork() not so obviously **does exist** on Windows :) See my answer.

Answer (score 28):

Contrary to both existing answers (from OJ and Vincent Robert) fork() does exist on high-end versions of Windows. It's part of *Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications* (SUA) earlier called *Microsoft Windows Services for UNIX* (SFU), earlier called *Interix*.

Citing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interix, SUA is available on

- Windows Server 2003 R2 (all editions) - version 5.2
- Windows Vista (Ultimate and
  Enterprise editions) - version 6.0
- Windows Server 2008 (all editions) -
  version 6.0
- Windows Server 2008 R2 and Microsoft
  Windows 7 - version 6.1

All you have to do to use fork() is to install free *SUA SDK*. Depending on your target system you need one of the following:

- [*Utilities and Software Development
  Kit (SDK) for Subsystem for
  UNIX-based Applications*](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8B4987E6-D960-49A2-BF52-D3FBD654254C)
- [*Utilities and SDK for Subsystem for
  UNIX-based Applications in Microsoft
  Windows Vista RTM/Windows Vista SP1
  and Windows Server 2008 RTM*](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=93FF2201-325E-487F-A398-EFDE5758C47F&displaylang=en)
- [*Utilities and SDK for Subsystem for
  UNIX-based Applications in Microsoft
  Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008
  R2*](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=dc03485b-629b-49a6-b5ef-18617d1a9804)

You can also take a look at [Does Interix implement fork()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371442/)

Comment: So what you're saying is "Fork does exist so long as you make sure it does by either using the correct version of Windows and installing an SDK that enables it". IMHO, it may as well not exist. `CreateProcess` is a much easier and better option for Windows dev (imho of course). Cheers!

Comment: No Windows is an easier and much better option.

Comment: Sadly it seems SUA is deprecated in Windows 8, and "will be completely removed from the next release": http://brianreiter.org/2011/09/15/sua-deprecated-in-windows-8/

Comment: @RichieHindle But now we are about to get a replacement in WSL apparently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux

Comment: @SørenBoisen: Yes!  I've yet to look at it, but it does look very promising.  We're currently using Cygwin, which isn't the most stable of things.  A "real" Linux commandline subsystem for Windows ought to be a much better alternative.

Comment: @RichieHindle Why not just use GNU/Linux then? It'll give you the most "real" Linux command line then. With WSL your abilities are limited.

Comment: This is *not* fork for windows but for the unix subsystem. You can not use it from a normal windows app.

Answer (score 6):

`fork` does not exist on Windows. You have to use a Window specific API called [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Contrary to `fork`, `CreateProcess` needs the path to the EXE. You can retrieve the path of the current EXE by calling [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28VS.85%29.aspx) with a NULL parameter.

Comment: fork() **does exist** on Windows :) See my answer.