# Linux patch command utility for Windows

Tags: windows, patch

Are there any Windows port of Linux patch command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is available from gnuwin32: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm

Answer (score 1):

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) works great for that and integrates nicely with Windows Explorer. There are also multiple ports of "patch.exe" as well as [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org/) and [Interix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746043/where-does-microsoft-windows-7-posix-implementation-currently-stands/4746119#4746119) (built in to newer Windows versions).

Comment: afaik TSVN can generate diffs, but not apply them using patch. Am I not right?