# How to Install a Patch in PHP

Tags: php

I need to install this patch in my PHP code:

https://bugs.php.net/patch-display.php?bug_id=44522&patch=uploads_larger_than_2g_HEAD_v2&revision=latest

Can any body explain how?

My PHP Version : 5.4.10

Comment: It looks one must also google 'how to run a patch' after finding a patch like i  did for the first time when i had this kind of error. yikes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must have the source and patch file before you can patch it. Its quite simple.

1. Go to the root directory of PHP 5.4 source code
2. Run `patch -p0 < /path/to/patch.patch`
3. If it shows an error, undo it by `patch -R < /path/to/patch.patch`. and adjust the **-p *num*** value. and go to step 2. Here *-p* is the smallest prefix containing num leading slashes from each file name found in the patch file. A sequence of one or more adjacent slashes is counted as a single slash. This controls how file names found in the patch file are treated, in case you keep your files in a different directory than the person who sent out the patch. For example, supposing the file name in the patch file was

   ```
   /u/howard/src/blurfl/blurfl.c
   ```

   setting `-p0` gives the entire file name unmodified, `-p1` gives

   ```
   u/howard/src/blurfl/blurfl.c
   ```

   without the leading slash, `-p4` gives

   ```
   blurfl/blurfl.c
   ```

   and not specifying `-p` at all just gives you `blurfl.c`. Whatever you end up with is looked for either in the current directory, or the directory specified by the `-d` option. 
   The number after `-p` can be determined by following
4. After that you need to **compile** this patched version of PHP. Compiling instructions are included PHP source directory. To build it in Unix use `README.UNIX-BUILD-SYSTEM` file and for Windows use `README.WIN32-BUILD-SYSTEM` file.

Comment: .. and after that you'll have to build PHP, just .. to make sure the asker understands that. :-) There might also be better ways to do it depending on the distribution used (if on linux) which will allow you to use the existing build procedure and source.

Comment: Thanks. Added that information

Comment: How would one do this in a Windows environment?

Comment: @user752746 the process is same. There is a [patch utility for window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780282/linux-patch-command-utility-for-windows). And see php.net for compiling PHP on windows.

Comment: Thanks @Shiplu Mokaddim! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Download your file as something like `php_upload_larger_than_2g.patch`.

Place it on your system.

Run:
`patch /path/to/patch/php_upload_larger_than_2g.patch /path/to/patching/file/whatever.php`

This should 'patch' that file. Note this only works in Unix-like systems.