# install posix on windows 7 32bit is it posible?

Tags: windows, posix

I am using xampp 1.7 and now want to install posix. Is it posible to install posix on windows 7 32bit?

Comment: What do you mean by "install posix"? POSIX is an API and command standard, not software.

Comment: Possible dup of [Where does Microsoft Windows 7 POSIX implementation currently stands?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4746043/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what Microsoft provides for Windows 7 Ultimate and Enterprise editions:
[Utilities and SDK for Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications in Microsoft Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2391)

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin provides a POSIX sort of environment for Windows. Another option would be to use a VM tool like VirtualBox (free) and run linux in a virtual machine.