# multiprocessing.freeze_support()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, py2exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

Why does the multiprocessing module need to call a specific [function](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support) to work when being "frozen" to produce a windows executable?

Comment: Without checking into it too much, I'd guess that it's because multiprocessing needs to know about the python interpreter it's running in so that it can invoke more of them, and because packaging like py2exe do unusual things to the modules included which also need to be accounted for to import them.

Comment: I appreciate your extremely helpful comment on my answer regarding comparators!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The reason is lack of `fork()` on Windows (which is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4243880/95735) entirely true). Because of this, on Windows the fork is *simulated* by creating a **new** process in which code, which on Linux is being run in child process, is being run. As the code is to be run in technically unrelated process, it has to be delivered there before it can be run. The way it's being delivered is first it's being pickled and then sent through the pipe from the original process to the new one. In addition this new process is being informed it has to run the code passed by pipe, by passing `--multiprocessing-fork` command line argument to it. If you take a look at [implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d9893d13c628/Lib/multiprocessing/forking.py#l302) of `freeze_support()` function its task is to check if the process it's being run in is supposed to run code passed by pipe or not.

Comment: One thing which is not 100% clear is the object/method which prepares the new process to be run must call freeze_support()? And that could be anywhere within the object/method but before the Process.start() method is called?

Comment: I would like to get an answer to this question posed by @Har as well, if you know it.  The PyInstaller recipe calls for invoking that outside of one's custom the Process class.  Is that needed? Can I not just put that freeze_support() in that object's init()? That would be a hell of a lot cleaner!

Comment: Or, in the "static" class scope space (sorry I don't know the Python terminology for such)?  This is what I'm talking about btw: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Multiprocessing