# cx_freeze creates multiple instances of program

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.3, cx-freeze, pyqt5

I'm trying to compile some `Python 3.3` code using `cx_freeze` and, after compiling, the resulting `test.exe` file will create an indefinite number of instances of the program, causing my Windows 7 system to become unstable. It works just as intended when just running in Python, but once compiled it causes issues. Here are my imports in my main script:

```
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep, time
from inspect import getmembers
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from main_ui import Ui_MainWindow           # Generated UI from pyuic, imports 
                                            # QtWidgets, QtCore, and QtGui
from devices import Device1, Device2        # Both are serial.Serial objects
```

The `setup.py` script:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

product_name = 'Product Name'

path_platforms = ("C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll",
                  "platforms\qwindows.dll")

includes = ['PyQt5.QtWidgets', 'PyQt5.QtCore', 'PyQt5.QtGui']
include_files = [path_platforms]
excludes = ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'curses', 'email', 'pywin.debugger',
            'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs', 'tcl',
            'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter']
packages = ['os']
path = []

bdist_msi_options = {'add_to_path':   False}

build_exe_options = {'includes':      includes,
                     'include_files': include_files,
                     'excludes':      excludes,
                     'packages':      packages,
                     'path':          path,
                     'silent':        True}

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

exe = Executable(script='main.pyw',
                 base=base,
                 targetName='test.exe')

setup(name=product_name,
      version='1.0',
      description='The Test Program',
      executables=[exe],
      options = {'bdist_msi': bdist_msi_options, 'build_exe': build_exe_options})
```

And when I run `python setup.py build`, the following error occurs:

```
Missing modules:
? System imported from serial.serialcli
? TERMIOS imported from serial.serialposix
? __main__ imported from bdb
? _gestalt imported from platform
? _posixsubprocess imported from subprocess
? clr imported from serial.serialcli
```

Despite these errors, it still generates a `test.exe` file. When I execute it, it generates a seemingly infinite number of windows and the only way to stop it is to hard reset the computer. Again, the main script works just fine running under Python, but fails once compiled. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: As requested, here is my main script:

```
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue, freeze_support
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep, time
from inspect import getmembers
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from main_ui import Ui_MainWindow           # Generated by pyuic
import parts                                # Imports time.sleep, datetime.datetime, and threading.Thread
from devices import GwPowerSupply, DataQ    # Imports time.sleep and serial.Serial
# GwPowerSupply is a serial.Serial object to handle communications with a GwInstek PSP-603
# DataQ is also a serial.Serial object to handle communications with a DataQ-155


def file_logger(message):
    logging = True
    if logging:
        with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write('{}: {}\n'.format(time(), message))


def compute():
    """
    A function, designed as an independent process, to gather data from the DataQ and Power Supply
    input queues, convert to human values, and output as a single queue
    """
    compute.running = True
    compute.paused = False
    # The initial dict to pass on to the queue
    data_dict = {'upstream': 0, 'downstream': 0, 'high_flow': 0, 'low_flow': 0, 'voltage': 0, 'current': 0, 'offset': 0}
    while compute.running:
        if compute.paused or compute.input_queue.empty():
            continue
        # Get the raw voltage data and convert to pressure/flow
        analog_input = compute.input_queue.get()
        file_logger('Compute received {}'.format(analog_input))
        if analog_input is None:
            continue
        # Four items comes from the DataQ for pressures and flow
        if len(analog_input) == 4:
            # Pressure Transducers are both 1-11V, 0-500 PSI
            if isinstance(analog_input[0], (float, int)):
                data_dict['upstream'] = (analog_input[0]-1) * 50
            if isinstance(analog_input[1], (float, int)):
                data_dict['downstream'] = (analog_input[1]-1) * 50
            # High Flow is 0-5V, 0-1000 Liters/min
            if isinstance(analog_input[2], (float, int)):
                data_dict['high_flow'] = (analog_input[2]*200) * .035147     # Convert SLM to SCFM
            # Low Flow is 0-5V, 0-5 Liters/min
            if isinstance(analog_input[3], (float, int)):
                data_dict['low_flow'] = analog_input[3] * 1000               # Convert SLM to SCCM
        # Two items are from the power supply for voltage and current
        elif len(analog_input) == 2:
            if isinstance(analog_input[0], (float, int)):
                data_dict['voltage'] = analog_input[0]
            if isinstance(analog_input[1], (float, int)):
                data_dict['current'] = analog_input[1]
        # A single item is the offset from the Valve program
        elif len(analog_input) == 1:
            data_dict['offset'] = analog_input[0]
        else:
            return
        compute.output_queue.put(data_dict)
        file_logger('Compute put out {}'.format(data_dict))


def data_q_producer():
    """
    A function, designed as an independent process, to gather data from the DataQ and feed it
    to the computing process
    """
    # Initialize COM port
    data_q = DataQ('COM4')
    data_q.start()
    # Continuously gather data
    while True:
        if not data_q.paused and not data_q.stopped:
            # Gather data and put to queue, either for response or normal
            file_logger('Getting Data from DataQ')
            if data_q.response:
                data = data_q.get_response_data()
                data_q_producer.response_queue.put(data)
            else:
                data = data_q.get_data()
                data_q_producer.queue.put(data)
            file_logger('Got {} from DataQ'.format(data))
        # If a command is received, such as to energize a relay, handle
        if not data_q_producer.output.empty():
            output = data_q_producer.output.get()
            file_logger('Sending {} to DataQ'.format(output))
            # Strings are to stop, run response, etc.
            if isinstance(output, str):
                if output == 'stop':
                    data_q.set_output(0, 0, 0, 0)
                    data_q.stop()
                    data_q.close()
                    data_q_producer.queue.put([])
                    return
                elif output == 'start resp':
                    data_q.response = True
                    data_q.pause()
                    data_q.start_resp()
                    data_q.start()
                elif output == 'stop resp':
                    print('Stopping Response Test')
                    data_q.pause()
                    data_q.setup()
                    data_q.start()
                    data_q.response = False
            # If a single integer is received, it is the new leakage offset.
            elif isinstance(output, float):
                data_q_producer.queue.put([output, ])
            # A List is to set the digital outputs
            elif isinstance(output, list):
                data_q.set_output(output[0], output[1], output[2], output[3])


def pps_producer():
    """
    A function, designed as an independent process, to gather data from the Power Supply and feed it
    to the computing process
    """
    # Initialize COM port
    pps = GwPowerSupply('COM1')
    pps.set_relay(True)
    # Continuously gather voltage and current readings
    while True:
        file_logger('Getting Data from Power Supply')
        voltage = pps.get_value('V')
        current = pps.get_value('A')
        file_logger('Got {}V, {}A from power supply'.format(voltage, current))
        pps_producer.queue.put([voltage, current])
        # If a command is received to change voltage, current, etc.; handle
        if not pps_producer.output.empty():
            output = pps_producer.output.get()
            file_logger('Got {} for Power Supply'.format(output))
            # Bool is to set the relay on or off
            if isinstance(output, bool):
                pps.set_relay(output)
            # String is primarily to stop the power supply (set the relay to Off)
            elif isinstance(output, str) and output == 'stop':
                pps.set_relay(False)
                pps.close()
                pps_producer.queue.put([])
                return
            # A tuple is changing a power supply output setting
            else:
                pps.set_value(output[0], output[1])


def pool_init(input_queue, output_queue, data_q_out, pps_out, response_queue):
    """
    Initializes the above functions with external queue variables.
    see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3843313/852994 for more details
    """
    compute.output_queue = output_queue
    compute.input_queue = input_queue

    data_q_producer.queue = input_queue
    data_q_producer.output = data_q_out
    data_q_producer.response_queue = response_queue

    pps_producer.queue = input_queue
    pps_producer.output = pps_out


class MainGui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """
    The Main interface builder for the program
    """
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize MainGui and create the window
        super(MainGui, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # The current valve part being tested
        self.valve = None
        # Disables the 'Energize' button when running ATP
        self.auto_mode = False

        # The current measured leakage offset based on the current run's test
        self.measured_offset = 0
        # The leakage offset table based on initial testing
        # @TODO: retest offsets and go to 450 PSI
        self.offset_table = ((-50, 30), (0, 31), (50, 44), (100, 37), (150, 41), (200, 44),
                         (250, 49), (300, 54), (350, 63), (400, 72), (450, 81))
        # A table of calculated leakage offsets to give single-incremental points based on the
        # above tested values
        self.calculated_offsets = []
        for i in range(len(self.offset_table)-1):
            for x in range(self.offset_table[i][0], self.offset_table[i-1][0]):
                x1 = self.offset_table[i][0]
                x2 = self.offset_table[i+1][0]
                y1 = self.offset_table[i][1]
                y2 = self.offset_table[i+1][1]
                y = ((x-x1) * (y2-y1)) / (x2-x1) + y1
                self.calculated_offsets.append(y)

        # Connect UI clicks and presses to commands
        self.ui.btn_all.clicked.connect(lambda: self.select_all_tests(True))
        self.ui.btn_none.clicked.connect(lambda: self.select_all_tests(False))
        self.ui.comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.select_part)
        self.ui.btn_energize.clicked.connect(self.energize)
        self.ui.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.start_tests)
        self.ui.btn_skip.clicked.connect(self.skip_press)

        # Select the initial part
        self.select_part()

        # Initialize queues
        self.input_queue = Queue(10)
        self.output_queue = Queue(10)
        self.data_q_out = Queue(10)
        self.pps_out = Queue(10)
        self.response_queue = Queue(400)
        self.test_queue = Queue(5)
        self.log_queue = Queue(10)

        # Initialize timer to update on-screen values
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_data)
        self.timer.start(25)

        # Initialize process pool
        self.pool = Pool(processes=4, initializer=pool_init,
                         initargs=(self.input_queue, self.output_queue, self.data_q_out,
                                   self.pps_out, self.response_queue))

        # Place the data producing functions into the process pool
        self.pool.apply_async(func=data_q_producer)
        self.pool.apply_async(func=compute)
        self.pool.apply_async(func=pps_producer)

    def closeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Verify COM ports are closed properly before exiting
        file_logger('Attempting Exit')
        self.timer.stop()
        self.test_queue.put('ESC')
        self.data_q_out.put('stop')
        self.pps_out.put('stop')
        sleep(.5)
        file_logger('Exited')

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        file_logger('Keypress Event: {}'.format(event.key()))
        # Capture different key presses for different functions
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            self.test_queue.put(float(self.ui.lineEdit.text()))
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Backspace:
            self.test_queue.put('ESC')
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_S:
        self.test_queue.put('SKIP')

    def skip_press(self):
        file_logger('Skip press Event')
        self.test_queue.put('SKIP')

    def print_to_log(self, text):
        # Enter a line into the log with auto-scrolling
        self.ui.log_output.append(text)
        cursor = self.ui.log_output.textCursor()
        QtGui.QTextCursor.movePosition(cursor, QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
        self.ui.log_output.setTextCursor(cursor)

    def update_data(self):
        # Update status boxes
        if not self.output_queue.empty():
            file_logger('Update Interface Event')
            data_dict = self.output_queue.get()
            # Before calculating corrected leakage, get the offset
            self.measured_offset = data_dict['offset']
            # Modify low flow with offset
            data_dict['low_flow'] -= self.measured_offset - self.calculated_offsets[int(data_dict['upstream'])]
            # Update the status on the UI
            self.ui.upstream_pressure.setText('{:.1f}'.format(data_dict['upstream']))
            self.ui.downstream_pressure.setText('{:.1f}'.format(data_dict['downstream']))
            self.ui.flow_sensor.setText('{:.2f}'.format(data_dict['high_flow']))
            self.ui.leakage_sensor.setText('{:.0f}'.format(data_dict['low_flow']))
            self.ui.voltage.setText('{:.2f}'.format(data_dict['voltage']))
            self.ui.current.setText('{:.3f}'.format(data_dict['current']))
            # Pass the values on to the test queue so the ATP process can use them
            self.test_queue.put(data_dict)
            if self.test_queue.full():
                self.test_queue.get()
            file_logger('Updated Interface')
        # Update log
        if not self.log_queue.empty():
            text = self.log_queue.get()
            file_logger('Printing to log: {}'.format(text))
            # For the countdown timer, delete the previous line, but not the first count!
            if isinstance(text, int) and text != 1:
                cursor = self.ui.log_output.textCursor()
                QtGui.QTextCursor.movePosition(cursor, QtGui.QTextCursor.End, QtGui.QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)
                QtGui.QTextCursor.movePosition(cursor, QtGui.QTextCursor.StartOfLine, QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
                QtGui.QTextCursor.removeSelectedText(cursor)
                # Delete last newline character so the number doesn't print on the next line
                QtGui.QTextCursor.deletePreviousChar(cursor)
            self.print_to_log(str(text))
            file_logger('Printed to log: {}'.format(text))

    def select_all_tests(self, state=True):
        # Select (or deselect if state is False) all tests
        for i in range(len(self.ui.listWidget)):
            self.ui.listWidget.item(i).setSelected(state)

    def select_part(self):
        # Update test list with a new part every time the combo box is changed
        part_name = self.ui.comboBox.currentText()
        for name, obj in getmembers(parts):
            # Get the objects only labled as 'Part'
            if 'Part' in name:
                # Get the object with a part name that corresponds the the selected part
                if part_name in obj().part_name:
                    self.valve = obj()
                    # Clear out the current contents of the test list
                    self.select_all_tests(False)
                    self.ui.listWidget.clear()
                    # Update test list with new tests
                    for test in self.valve.procedure:
                        self.ui.listWidget.addItem(test[0])
                    # Pre-select all tests
                    self.select_all_tests()
                    # Set Coils up properly; if there is only one coil in the unit, disable the second coil
                    self.ui.coil_1.setChecked(True)
                    if self.valve.coils < 2:
                        self.ui.coil_2.setChecked(False)
                        self.ui.coil_2.setEnabled(False)
                    else:
                        self.ui.coil_2.setEnabled(True)
                        self.ui.coil_2.setChecked(True)
                    return

    def energize(self):
        # Energize function for the energize button, but only if not running any test!
        if self.auto_mode:
            pass
        else:
            if self.ui.btn_energize.isChecked():
                coil1 = int(self.ui.coil_1.checkState() / 2)
                coil2 = int(self.ui.coil_2.checkState() / 2)
                self.data_q_out.put([coil1, coil2, 2, 2])
            else:
                self.data_q_out.put([0, 0, 2, 2])

    def start_tests(self):
        file_logger('Starting Tests')
        # Starts the testing thread
        self.ui.log_output.setHtml('')
        t = Thread(target=self.run_tests)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    def run_tests(self):
        # Don't let the user try to start while running nor change the part number mid-test!
        self.ui.btn_start.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.comboBox.setEnabled(False)
        line = '-----------------------------------------------'
        for test in self.valve.procedure:
            # Verify the test is selected to run by iterating through all the test items in
            # the test list and, if matching the current test name, verify the checked state
            for i in range(len(self.ui.listWidget)):
                if test[0] == self.ui.listWidget.item(i).text() and self.ui.listWidget.item(i).isSelected():
                    file_logger('Testing {}'.format(test[0]))
                    self.log_queue.put('<b>{1}\r\nRunning {0}\r\n{1}</b> '.format(test[0], line))
                    test[1](self.log_queue, self.test_queue, self.pps_out, self.data_q_out, self.response_queue)
                    # Tell the user of an escape or a skip
                    if self.valve.escape:
                        file_logger('Escaped'.format(test[0]))
                        self.log_queue.put('<b><font color="blue">Escaped</b></font> ')
                        self.ui.btn_start.setEnabled(True)
                        self.ui.comboBox.setEnabled(True)
                        self.valve.escape = False
                        # If escaping, break out of all loops
                    return
                elif self.valve.skip:
                    file_logger('Skipped'.format(test[0]))
                    self.log_queue.put('<b><font color="orange">Skipped</b></font> ')
                    self.valve.skip = False
                else:
                    file_logger('Test Successful')
                # Once the test is found, break out of the test name matching loop
                break
            # If the test is not selected, notify user by displaying 'Skipping'
            elif test[0] == self.ui.listWidget.item(i).text():
                self.log_queue.put('<b>{1}</b>\r\nSkipping {0}'.format(test[0], line))
                break
        # Re-enable starting tests and selecting part numbers
        self.ui.btn_start.setEnabled(True)
        self.ui.comboBox.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()

    #input_queue = Queue(10)
    #output_queue = Queue(10)
    #data_q_out = Queue(10)
    #pps_out = Queue(10)
    #response_queue = Queue(400)
    ## Initialize process pool
    #pool = Pool(processes=4, initializer=pool_init,
    #            initargs=(input_queue, output_queue, data_q_out, pps_out, response_queue))
    #
    ## Place the data producing functions into the process pool
    #pool.apply_async(func=data_q_producer)
    #pool.apply_async(func=compute)
    #pool.apply_async(func=pps_producer)

    file_logger('####### NEW RUN #######\n')
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainGui()
    window.show()
    file_logger('####### END RUN #######\n')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Does your application use `multiprocessing`, or start subprocesses using `sys.executable`?

Comment: It's using an asynchronous pool from `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Try using [freeze_support()](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support). multiprocessing starts further Python processes using `sys.executable`, but in your frozen exe, that points to your application, not to Python.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help. It did get me thinking about where the pool is inside the `__init__` of my main class. I tried moving it outside, under `if __name__ == '__main__':`, but that didn't help either....

Comment: Can you show your code? You do need to ensure that it's only called when `__name__ == '__main__'`. Multiprocessing on Windows is rather ugly, unfortunately, because of the lack of `fork()`.

Comment: I have the same issue but with python 2.7 and multiprocessing

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the following code to your main, before anything else:

```
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
freeze_support()
```

See this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922597/multiprocessing-freeze-support/18195951)

Comment: Worked for me. It must be the **first** line in `__main__` though.