# where to put freeze_support() in a Python script?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, runtime-error

I am confused about using `freeze_support()` for `multiprocessing` and I get a `Runtime Error` without it. I am only running a script, not defining a function or a module. Can I still use it? Or should the packages I'm importing be using it?

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#miscellaneous) is the documentation.

Note that the specific issue is about `scikit-learn` calling `GridSearchCV` which tries to spawn processes in parallel. I am not sure if my script needs to be frozen for this, or the some code that's called (from the Anaconda distro). If details are relevant to this question, please head over to the more specific [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24363300/938408).

Comment: How is your script executed?

Comment: @dano OK, then the specific question is relevant. I have my entire code pasted there. (But the link pointed to the wrong question, I fixed it.) Executed in a dedicated Python interpreter (from Spyder).

Answer (score 113, accepted):

On Windows **all** of your `multiprocessing`-using code must be guarded by `if __name__ == "__main__":`

So to be safe, I would put all of your the code currently at the top-level of your script in a `main()` function, and then just do this at the top-level:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

See the "Safe importing of main module" sub-section [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) for an explanation of why this is necessary. You probably don't need to call `freeze_support` at all, though it won't hurt anything to include it.

Note that it's a best practice to use the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard for scripts anyway, so that code isn't unexpectedly executed if you find you need to `import` your script into another script at some point in the future.

Comment: Sounds great, thanks, I'll let you know how it ran, and then I'm happy to accept.

Comment: the only scenario this doesn't cover is when someone creates an object that inherits from Process, i.e: class myProcess(Process), where do you put then freeze_support in that scenario?

Comment: Thank you. This error of not using multiprocessing inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` came as a surprise to me. I was unaware of the multiprocessing requirement though I always used multiprocessing functions inside the `if` clause. This was the first time I used the code outside of the `if` clause and it gave the error `RuntimeError: Attempt to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase`