# Scikit-Learn GridSearchCV: Avoid function to copy data for each process in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I use sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV in parallel with several cpus/cores. Calling the fit method creates several copies (one for each process) of my data. That causes my processes to crash due to memory limitations.

Is there a way to prevent the function from copying the data for each process? Can I use shared memory for all cores?

Comment: maybe this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24411581/288875 gives you some hints

Comment: Thank you. That looks promising. I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

python by default creates a new process for each parallel task. This new process copies the data. I would recommend using the multiprocess shared environment to avoid this. You can see an example in https://github.com/alvarouc/polyssifier/blob/master/polyssifier/polyssifier.py#L87

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And thank you for sharing with the community!