# How to get `setup.py test` working with `multiprocessing` on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, setuptools

## Issue

I am trying to get `setup.py test` working with a package that uses multiprocessing on Windows. I have the following scenario:

- A regular python package folder structure
- with a package
- a test folder and
- a `setup.py`.

Running

```
python -m unittest
```

from the top directory executes my tests without complaints. However, when calling

```
python setup.py test
```

I get the well known `freeze_support` issue (see several questions here on SO):

```
RuntimeError: 
    An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
    current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...
    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

However, following
[where to put freeze_support() in a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374288/where-to-put-freeze-support-in-a-python-script) I actually have the described guards in place in all my files, possibly in way too many.

**Question 1:** What do I have to change in my project for `setup.py test` to work with my multiprocessing using function?

**Question 2:** Which of my placed `freeze_support()` are actually needed? As far as I know, this is normally only needed when compiling a frozen executable.

## MWE

#### Folder structure

```
project
│   setup.py
│
└─── my_package
│    │   __init__.py
│    │   my_package.py
│   
└─── test
│    │   __init__.py
│    │   test_it.py
```

The `__init__.py` files are empty, the other ones are:

#### my_package.py

```
import multiprocessing

def say_hi(arg):
    print('hi')

def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
    pool.map(say_hi, range(1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    main()
```

#### test_it.py

```
import multiprocessing
import unittest

from my_package import my_package

class TestIt(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_say_hi(self):
        my_package.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```

#### setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import setuptools
import multiprocessing

setuptools.setup(
    name = "my_package"
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the similar problem.
I found that the new process created by multiprocessing calls `setuptools.setup` method when the test is executed via **setup.py** and this affects something. (I'm not clear about the root cause...)

In my case, this **setup.py** resolved that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import setuptools

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setuptools.setup(
        name = "my_package",
        ....,
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, I think this program runs **if setuptools.setup is executed only when __name__ == ‘main’ holds.**

**Root cause**

When you spawn the process with multiprocessing, modules are imported, **setting __name__ attributes to be “__mp_main__”, (not __main__).**

This is a code snippet from **_fixup_main_from_path** in **multiprocessing.spawn.py**

```
# If the parent process has sent a path through rather than a module
# name we assume it is an executable script that may contain
# non-main code that needs to be executed
old_main_modules.append(current_main)
main_module = types.ModuleType("__mp_main__")
main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
                              run_name="__mp_main__")
main_module.__dict__.update(main_content)
sys.modules['__main__'] = sys.modules['__mp_main__'] = main_module
```

Therefore, if setuptools.setup is executed at the top level of module, infinite recursion occurs.