# Issues when parallelize Monte Carlo method with python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, python-multiprocessing, montecarlo

I want to speed up a Monte Carlo Method which bases on numpy manipulation with the Multiprocessing module. I've read [enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process) and wrote a code like follows for some tasks:

```
import func1, func2, func3, ... #some manipulations on the SAME numpy ndarray but each of then works independantly returns a independant result
import multiprocessing as mp
if __name__ == '__main__':
   with mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
   task1 = pool.Process(target=fun1, args(arg1, arg2, ...)
   task2 = pool.Process(target=fun2, args(arg1, arg2, ...)
   task3 = pool.Process(target=fun3, args(arg1, arg2, ...)
   ...
   task1.start()
   task2.start()
   task3.start()
   ...
   variable1 = task1.join() #In my case, I need to get the returns of these functions
   variable2 = task2.join()
   variable3 = task3.join()
   ...
```

Like most of the tutorials. But I got a

> RuntimeError:An attempt has been made to start a new process before
>   the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

I'm really new in this field and struggling for days before I post this question here. Could somebody kindly give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out this RunTimeError issue when I run the same programme on a MacOS. Actually, this RuntimeError is due to the way [how Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374288/where-to-put-freeze-support-in-a-python-script) compile a .py file.

To correct this, the simpliest way is to pass the body of the programme into a function `main()` (eventhough in my case, it's complicated) then add the `freeze_support()` in the `multipleprocessing` module. So it will finally look like this:
import func1, func2, func3, ... #some manipulations on the SAME numpy ndarray but each of then works independantly returns a independant result

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import freeze_support()
def main():
   with mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
      task1 = pool.Process(target=fun1, args(arg1, arg2, ...)
      task2 = pool.Process(target=fun2, args(arg1, arg2, ...)
      task3 = pool.Process(target=fun3, args(arg1, arg2, ...)
      ...
      task1.start()
      task2.start()
      task3.start()
      ...
      variable1 = task1.join() #In my case, I need to get the returns of these functions
      variable2 = task2.join()
      variable3 = task3.join()
      ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
   freeze_support()
   main()
```