# Dask Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, future, dask

I am trying to run the following code. It works if executed in a shell but crashes if executed as macro (py macro.py). Please could you tell me what's wrong. 
Thank you

```
import os
import sys
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client

def inc(x):
    return x + 1

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

client = Client(n_workers=2, threads_per_worker=2, memory_limit='1GB')

a = client.submit(inc, 10)
b = client.submit(inc, 20)
print(a.result())
print(b.result())
```

Comment: Can you post an error message? Also it's not clear to me at least what you mean by run as a macro (unless py is an alias for python or python3)?

Comment: `if executed as macro` Python doesn’t have macros, do you mean that the _file_ is named “macros”?

Comment: I meant storing the code in macro.py and executing the code (py macro.py)

Comment: The error message is very long. Here is part of it :

Comment: .....

RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with running scripts that create processes.  You need to create your `Client` object within the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block

See the answer in [where to put freeze_support() in a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374288/where-to-put-freeze-support-in-a-python-script) for more information.

Comment: thank you MRocklin . One last question. Is this recommandation Windows specific? I use a Mac.

Comment: The `__main__` thing is general good practice, but there are additional constraints on windows which require freeze.