# Python multiprocessing RuntimeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a simple function that I intend to run in Parallel using the Python multiprocessing module. However I get the following error `RuntimeError: An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.` The error suggests that I add this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
freeze_support()
```

And most posts online suggest the same like this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24374288/8602367).

I added it and it works but I don't seem to understand why it's necessary for such a simple piece of code.

**Code without __name__=="__main__" (throws RuntimeError)**

```
import multiprocessing
import time

start = time.perf_counter()


def do_something():
    print('Sleeping 1 second...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Done sleeping...')

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
p1.start()
p2.start()

finish = time.perf_counter()

print(f'Finished in {round(finish - start, 2)} second(s)')
```

**Code with __name__=="__main__" (doesn't throw RuntimeError)**

```
import multiprocessing
import time

start = time.perf_counter()


def do_something():
  print('Sleeping 1 second...')
  time.sleep(1)
  print('Done sleeping...')


def main():
   p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
   p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
   p1.start()
   p2.start()

   finish = time.perf_counter()
   print(f'Finished in {round(finish - start, 2)} second(s)')


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: Do you have the indention right in the first script? `do_something` creates a process that calls `do_something`, etc..., which would blow up fast except there is no top level call to `do_something` so no processes are created.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://bugs.python.org/issue37205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, `multiprocessing.Process` executes a fresh copy of python to run the code. It has to get the code you want to execute to load in that process so it pickles a snapshot of your current environment to expand in the child. For that to work, the child needs to reimport modules used by the parent. In particular, it needs to import the main script as a module. When you import, any code residing at module level executes.

So lets make the simplest case

foo.py

```
import multiprocessing as mp
process = mp.Process(target=print, args=('foo',))
process.start()
process.join()
```

`process.start()` executes a new python which imports `foo.py`. And there's the problem. That new `foo` will create *another* subprocess which will again import foo.py. So *yet another* process is created.

The would go on until you blow up your machine except that python detects the problem and raises the exception.

THE FIX

Python modules have the `__name__` attribute. If you run your program as a script, `__name__` is "**main**", otherwise, `__name__` is the name of your module. So, when a multiprocessing process is importing your main script to setup your environment, its name is not `__main__`. You can use that to make sure that your MP work is only done in the parent module.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # run as top level script, but not as imported module
    process = mp.Process(target=print, args=('foo',))
    process.start()
    process.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, I use a Mac OS (Mojave) but it still threw the error.