# Multiprocessing of image processing (EDITED)

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, multiprocessing, runtime-error

I have the following program:

```
daytime_images = os.listdir("D:/TR/Daytime/")
number_of_day_images = len(daytime_images)
day_value = 27

def find_RGB_day(clouds, red, green, blue):
    img = Image.open(clouds)
    img = img.convert('RGB')
    pixels_single_photo = []
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            h, s, v, = img.getpixel((x, y))
            if h <= red and s <= green and v <= blue:
                pixels_single_photo.append((x,y))
    return pixels_single_photo

number = 0

for _ in range(number_of_day_images):
    world_image = ("D:/TR/Daytime/" + daytime_images[number])
    pixels_found = find_RGB_day(world_image, day_value, day_value, day_value)
    coordinates.append(pixels_found)
    number = number+1
```

**EDITED**
I would want to execute the function using multiprocessor, so I tried:

```
for number in range(number_of_day_images):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=find_RGB_day,
        args=("D:/TR/IR_Photos/Daytime/" + daytime_images[number],27, 27, 27))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    number = number+1
    coordinates.append(p)
```

When executing it, a AttributeError happened and I don't know how to solve it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'find_RGB_day' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

I think this error may be related with the way I introduce the images into the program, where I get all names from a folder and then select element per element with number= number+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was working in parallel with [wagnifico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9899594/wagnifico) and tried the Pool (nice guess).
I did not have image files, so I have constructed the similar function using namedtuple to get as close as possible.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError
import os, time
import random
from collections import namedtuple


def find_RGB_day(red, green, blue):
    img = Image((256, 256))  # loading your image goes here eg. 256 x 256
    pixels_single_photo = []
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            h, s, v, = random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255)
            if h <= red and s <= green and v <= blue:
                pixels_single_photo.append((x,y))
    time.sleep(5)  # del this line, it imitates loading a big file
    return pixels_single_photo


if __name__ == '__main__':
    number_of_day_images = 5
    day_value = 27
    Image = namedtuple('Image',['size'])

    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:  # You can play with processes number
        multiple_results = [pool.apply_async(find_RGB_day, args=(27, 27, 27)) for i in range(number_of_day_images)]
        try:
            [print(res.get()) for res in multiple_results]
        except TimeoutError:
            print("We lacked patience and got a multiprocessing.TimeoutError")
```

I have used python documentation about 'Using a pool of workers', which you can find [HERE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

So instead of creating this loop of processes, the pool takes responsibility for all the computations.

```
for _ in range(number_of_day_images):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=find_RGB_day, args=("D:/TR/IR_Photos/Daytime/" + daytime_images[number], 27, 27, 27))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

You could have something like this:

```
multiple_results = [pool.apply_async(find_RGB_day, args=("D:/TR/IR_Photos/Daytime/" + daytime_images[number], 27, 27, 27)]
    try:
        [print(res.get()) for res in multiple_results]
```

In my code example 4 files load and build an array of multiple_results in around 5 seconds (because we have got 4 workers) and the last one fires after another 5 seconds.

[EDIT]
I have downloaded images and used this code to get all the coordinates of the desired pixels. (27, 27, 27) was too low for me, so I have used a different scale (31, 90, 170).

Enjoy.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError
import time, os
import random
from PIL import Image


def find_RGB_day(clouds, red, green, blue):
    img = Image.open(clouds)
    img = img.convert()
    pixels_single_photo = []
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            # print(img.getpixel((x, y)))
            h, s, v, = img.getpixel((x, y))
            if h <= red and s <= green and v <= blue:
                pixels_single_photo.append((x,y))
    return pixels_single_photo


def create_pool():
    coordinates = []
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        files_to_precess = [pool.apply_async(find_RGB_day,
                                             args=("D/TR/Daytime/" + daytime_images[number], 31, 90, 170))
                            for number in range(number_of_day_images)]
        try:
            coordinates = [res.get() for res in files_to_precess]  # processes get your data in here
        except TimeoutError:
            print("We lacked patience and got a multiprocessing.TimeoutError")
    return coordinates

if __name__ == '__main__':
    daytime_images = os.listdir("D/TR/Daytime/")
    number_of_day_images = len(daytime_images)
    print(number_of_day_images)
    day_value = 27
    coordinates = create_pool()
    [print(res) for res in coordinates]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my program I was looking for certain pixels that were added to pixels_single_photo and then, at the end of each loop, those pixels were kept in a list called coordinates (a list of lists) How can I implement this this this program?

Comment: You have got all the pixels inside  multiple_results  list of lists. Instead of just printing them out like I did, you can do with it whatever you please.
Just try my code and you will see all of them in there :)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, how can you store all the coords in a list called coordinates?  Trying with [coordinates.append(res.get()) for res in coordinates] I'm having the AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'. Thanks

Comment: Not a problem. I have corrected few lines in that last edit, so paste all after 'Enjoy'.
It should be 
coordinates = [res.get() for res in files_to_precess] 
where 
files_to_process list 
just stores all the desired processes, so you loop through it and res.get() them out one by one.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You should just do it as explained by the error message and add a main module:

```
def fun(inputs):
    # your function
    return outputs

if __name__ == '__main__':
   # your main code
   p = multiprocessing.Process(target=fun, args=(inputs,))
   p.start()
   p.join()
```

More details are available on [answers for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374288/where-to-put-freeze-support-in-a-python-script).

Also, there is an error in your code. You must split the function and arguments when calling your process: `target=fun, args=(inputs,)`, like I did in the example above. When you send the function with the arguments - `target=fun(inputs)` - you are actually not calling any process because you are just sending the output of your the function `fun` as the target, and not the function itself. It will raise an error because the output of your function is not callable (not a function by itself).

In order to adapt your call, with multiple arguments, you can use:

```
for number in range(number_of_days_images):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=find_RGB_day,
        args=("D:/TR/IR_Photos/Daytime/" + daytime_images[number],
              27, 27, 27)
    )
    # rest of your code ...
```

Moreover, I recommend you to use [pool.Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map), that will split a list of arguments between the desired number of workers and block the results. A nice description of how to implement it for a function with multiple arguments is availabe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/how-to-use-multiprocessing-pool-map-with-multiple-arguments).

Comment: Thanks. Where you can introduce the saving of pixels_single_photo into the list coordinates?

Comment: I am constantly receiving the attribute error described in the top of the page. Do you know what is this due to?

Comment: It looks like you have not defined the function. Make sure that it is already defined before you make the call.

Also, in your edit, you should remove `number = number + 1` as it is already being taken care by the for loop.