# Why the print execute 3 times out of main block in python Window?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm a newbee for `multiprocess` and try with a `multiprocess` demo in python.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def foo(a, b):
    print(a,b)
    ...

def bar(a, b):
    print(a,b)
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    func_list = [foo, bar]
    for func in func_list:
        pool.apply_async(func, (1, 2))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

print(123)
```

When I work with `win32` platform

`123` output always be `3` times

```
123
1 2
1 2
123
123
```

But when try this demo with `linux` it output once

```
1 2
1 2
123
```

Why this print execute 3 times out of main block in python Window?

Answer (score 1):

Thats a limitation of `multiprocessing` under Windows, because it has no `fork`. This is why a new process under Windows reimports all modules instead of inheriting the interpreter state from parent process. You have need to move `print(123)` under the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/24374798/725126

Comment: `Mac os` is same with window?