# Difference in behavior between os.fork and multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, fork, python-multiprocessing

I have this code :

```
import os

pid = os.fork()

if pid == 0:
    os.environ['HOME'] = "rep1"
    external_function()
else:
    os.environ['HOME'] = "rep2"
    external_function()
```

and this code :

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def f(conn):
    os.environ['HOME'] = "rep1"
    external_function()
    conn.send(some_data)
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ['HOME'] = "rep2"
    external_function()
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    print parent_conn.recv()
    p.join()
```

The `external_function` initializes an external programs by creating the necessary sub-directories in the directory found in the environment variable `HOME`.  This function does this work only once in each process.

With the first example, which uses `os.fork()`, the directories are created as expected. But with second example, which uses `multiprocessing`, only the directories in `rep2` get created.

Why isn't the second example creating directories in both `rep1` and `rep2`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you're seeing. I wrote an `external_function` like this: `def external_function(): print os.environ['HOME']`, and found that the `multiprocessing` example printed out exactly what I expected it to; 'rep1', 'rep2' and the string I sent back from `conn.send` were all printed.

Comment: I think you will find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276117/python-multiprocessing-process-vs-standalone-python-vm).

Comment: The function I execute is `getInstalledPackages` from https://github.com/vle-forge/pyvle/blob/master/src/pyvle.py.

Comment: @andi That's what I suspected. If you write an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I will do that. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is in detail addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276117/python-multiprocessing-process-vs-standalone-python-vm). There is also an explanation of differences between different OS.

One big issue is that the `fork` system call does not exist on Windows. Therefore, when running a Windows OS you cannot use this method. `multiprocessing` is a higher-level interface to execute a part of the currently running program. Therefore, it - as forking does - creates a copy of your process current state. That is to say, it takes care of the forking of your program for you.

Therefore, if available you could consider `fork()` a lower-level interface to forking a program, and the `multiprocessing` library to be a higher-level interface to forking.

Comment: Please, if anyone else has the same question as the user above, this answer doesn't provide anything but another link to go down. If you could put the relevant information in your answer, as the community guidelines request you do, I will remove my downvote.

Comment: I hope this is what you are asking for. Otherwise let me know. Thanks for your critics.

Comment: It actually doesn't create a copy of the current process in Windows. Otherwise, all the caveats listed [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) wouldn't be a problem. See my answer for more details.

Comment: 'takes care of forking for you' ... what if my program forks within lock. Is deadlock expected? If there's a layer of abstraction between me and the forking, the details are important.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question directly, there must be some side effect of `external_process` that makes it so that when the code is run in series, you get different results than if you run them at the same time. This is due to how you set up your code, and the lack of differences between `os.fork` and `multiprocessing.Process` in systems that `os.fork` is supported.

---

The only real difference between the `os.fork` and `multiprocessing.Process` is portability and library overhead, since `os.fork` is not supported in windows, and the `multiprocessing` framework is included to make `multiprocessing.Process` work. This is because `os.fork` is called by `multiprocessing.Process`, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2276366/786020) backs up.

The important distinction, then, is `os.fork` copies everything in the current process using Unix's forking, which means at the time of forking both processes are the same with PID differences. In Window's, this is emulated by rerunning all the setup code before the `if __name__ == '__main__':`, which is roughly the same as creating a subprocess using the `subprocess` library.

For you, the code snippets you provide are doing fairly different things above, because you call `external_function` in main before you open the new process in the second code clip, making the two processes run in series but in different processes. Also the pipe is unnecessary, as it emulates no functionality from the first code.

In Unix, the code snippets:

```
import os

pid = os.fork()

if pid == 0:
    os.environ['HOME'] = "rep1"
    external_function()
else:
    os.environ['HOME'] = "rep2"
    external_function()
```

and:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

def f():
    os.environ['HOME'] = "rep1"
    external_function()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    os.environ['HOME'] = "rep2"
    external_function()
    p.join()
```

should do exactly the same thing, but with a little extra overhead from the included multiprocessing library.

---

Without further information, we can't figure out what the issue is. If you can provide code that demonstrates the issue, that would help us help you.

Comment: The example of Dano is not the same as what my function do.

Comment: But his comment is still valid, we cannot reproduce the behavior you are encountering without some input from you.

Comment: If you want to reproduce the behavior I'm encountering, you must install a bunch of packages.

Comment: If Dano's edit is correct, then we cannot answer your question without at least getting the names of the packages.

Comment: You can answer my if you know the difference between them.

Comment: There are more issues here than the differences in the libraries. There may be side effects of `external_function` that we cannot account for, which is the only explanation for the behavior you describe that I know of. Additionally, as both my and Andi's answer say, the differences are that the `multiprocessing` library wraps `os.fork`.