# How to run python script on background/as a process?

Tags: python, process, background, background-process

I want to run a python script as a process/in the background. I searched and found `pythonw.exe` but when I do `pythonw.exe name_of_my_script.py` nothing happened. Am I doing something wrong and/or how else would I run it in the background?

This is part of my code that do problem  :

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

I will thank you for any help whatsoever.

**note:**
With the help of the comments here, I understood that also python.exe running don't work and bring error - NameError: name 'PROTOCOL_TLS' is not defined ( even tough in normal running it doesn't have errors.

**edit:**
i used http://pytoexe.com/ and i got exe file that work but the cmd console still exist ( mabye it because i use phantomjs ? ) [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJP88.png)

Comment: does your script work fine when you run it with python.exe?

Comment: What do you mean "in the background"? You can just run a python script in a terminal window and leave it running while you perform other tasks in other windows.

Comment: In Windows you need to create a Windows service. Look at Hammond & Robinson, *Python Programming on Win32*, Chapter 18, ISBN 978-1-56592-621-9.

Comment: 1.hmm when i run it with python.exe it doing error - NameError: name 'PROTOCOL_TLS' is not defined ( when i run it normally it doesn't have any error) mabye it's the problem?

2. i can leave the window terminal open but i want to run it without anything open - even not the terminal. think about it like a virus - the user don't know he exist , he don't leave after him open programs like terminal.
3. I will try thanks

Comment: What OS do you use? If you are on Linux/*nix, just run it from terminal and append `&` behind the command. For more info: https://kb.iu.edu/d/afnz

Comment: I have windows.

Comment: You should edit the Title of this question 'backgroung' to 'background'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own exe by going to **http://pytoexe.com** .
After that convert your script. Choose windows-based and convert it.
You'll not have any problems after that. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hii, first of all thanks alot, seconde, i did it and it's do what it need to do but the cmd console stays open because i use phantomjs and it opens a cmd console do you know what to do?

Comment: You need to choose window-based to be a background process.

Comment: I choosed window based option - it’s not open the console of the whole script but it opens a console every time i use phantomjs .

Comment: I will record my program and publish here

Comment: [see this video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDLWnXWNoQU&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: It doesn't work because the program phantomjs.exe opens a console, not the .exe. If phantomjs.exe is made to open a console, then it will open one. Try using another program.

Comment: Instead of phantomjs? I dont think there is more option :(

Comment: It’s strange because When i run it normally ( not converting to exe ) , the phamtomjs dont open console.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this by using `threading` module, and use `os.fork()` - but I'm not running Windows. I suggest having a look through [Difference in behavior between os.fork and multiprocessing.Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041935/difference-in-behavior-between-os-fork-and-multiprocessing-process) for other OSes.

Answer (score 0):

By "I want to run a python script as a process/in the background," do you mean make the window not visible? if so, just save the script as .pyw instead of .py

Comment: I tried to do pythonw.exe name_of_my_script.py(which is the same) but it didn't do anything, as i write, i think it because python.exe name_of_my_script.py raise this error     PROTOCOL_SSLv23 = PROTOCOL_TLS
NameError: name 'PROTOCOL_TLS' is not defined.
whereas name_of_my_script.py doesn't bring errors...

Comment: anyway, i tried to save it as .pyw and run in in the terminal but again, it didn't do anything just like pythonw.exe name_of_my_script.py

Do you know why when i run it in this way - python.exe name_of_my_script.py it raise error while running it in this way - name_of_my_script.py doesn't raise any error?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know why that happens. I made a keylogger just today and saved it as .pyw and it works just fine. I'm very sorry that I can't help

Comment: It’s ok :( , Thanks anyway

Comment: Hmmm... Just found out a way. Try using pyinstaller. Use the --noconsole option, like this: pyinstaller --noconsole scriptName.py

Comment: Hi, i done it buy i don't understand what it should do ... it just write alot of lines in the terminal like - 513 INFO: checking COLLECT - and add one file - nameofthescript.spec